# How to add an FTP user that doesn't have access to parent dirrectories?

Tags: vsftpd

I want to add user called `user` on my ftp server, and that user will have access on just `/home/user` folder...And I want to he hasn't got access in back folders, home, root and that, just `/home/user` but I don't know every command. How can this be done?

Comment: You'll need [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html), [`chgrp`](http://ss64.com/bash/chgrp.html), and [`chown`](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html). =) By default the user should usually should only have access to his home directory, so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Can you link me tutorial, i am beginner and totally noob with this :D

Comment: I can't find any tutorials, so I will try & write one - tutorial writing being something I am a total noob at.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these commands need to be run as root by the way, so for instance instead of `chmod ...`, it would be `sudo chmod...`

This all depends whether this  of *restricting* access to folder or *allowing* access to folders. This is on the [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) page, which is what makes it really useful:

[image]

**Owner** is the permissions on that file of the owner of the folder - usually the user that has created them - can be changed with `chown`.

**Group** is the permissions on that file of the group of the folder - can be changed with the `chown` or the `chgrp` commands.

**Other** is the permissions on that file of everyone who does not fall into the above two categories.

So running `chmod 600 /PATH/TO/FILE` will change the permissions so that  **only the owner** can read the file, and write to it. This is useful if `ristekga` is the only other user, as then they cannot access it, but the owner can.

You can also do the same for folders, but by using `chmod -R 600 /PATH/TO/FILE` so the contents of the folder is the same as well. You should be able to run this on all the folders not owned by `ristekga` to stop them accessing them.

If they are owned by `ristekga`, running `chown -R USERNAME:GROUP /PATH/TO/FOLDER` *(or `chown USERNAME:GROUP /PATH/TO/FILE`)* should work - where `USERNAME` is the name of the new owner, and `GROUP` is the name of the group the folder it is to part of - but this can *usually* be the same as the `USERNAME`.