# Resolved - Access denied. Trying to install Wordpress theme file

Tags: 13.10

I am in the process setting up Wordpress locally(not on the server) on my Inspirion 3520 that runs 13.10. I need to install a Theme and a plugin that was purchased. I am unable to copy and paste or move the file to /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes. I get "Access denied" and that I am not the owner.... How can I access or get privileges access and add the files I need to add?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a normal user you cannot simply copy files to system directories. Only root can do that. You can copy your file using the following command:

`sudo cp YOURFILE /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes/`

If you insist on using a file browser like Nautilus to do this, you can start Nautilus with super-user privileges, but I would personally avoid this. If at all, use with extreme caution:

`gksudo nautilus`

Finally, if you only want to install a theme for a single user, it is probably better to install it into your home directory, rather than a system directory.

Comment: You are supposed to use `gksudo` - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/11766/178596) - stops making the home directory only accessible as root.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the same computer, you should be able to copy the file with:

```
sudo cp /SOURCE/FILE /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DESTINATION-FILE
```

or a directory with

```
sudo cp -r /SOURCE/FOLDER/ /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DESTINATION-FOLDER/
```

If you want to **move** a file or folder, just use:

```
sudo mv /SOURCE/FILE /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DESTINATION-FILE
```

---

You could also just open file manager as root - **but this should be used with caution:**

```
gksudo nautilus
```

For more, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/11766/178596).

---

All of the above can be done in terminal, which in Unity can be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

---

## Edit:

If you want to modify the file as your normal user, just `chmod` on it. This change the permissions so that it can be modified by users other than root.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/wordpress/wp-content/themes/FILE
```

There is a manual page on chmod [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

---

## Another Edit:

A more secure way of doing it would be to make your user the 'owner' of the file - you can do this by:

```
sudo chown USERNAME:GROUP /PATH/TO/FILE/
```

You can usually use your `USERNAME` in the place of `GROUP`.

There is a another helpful web page [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)

I did a answer a while ago [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/385094/178596) that might be of use as well.

Comment: No luck. Here is what happened. I got this...karl@karl-Inspiron-3520:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for karl: 
root@karl-Inspiron-3520:/home/karl# sudo cp /home/karl/Downloads/IREX/irex /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/karl/Downloads/IREX/irex’
root@karl-Inspiron-3520:/home/karl# sudo cp /home/karl/Downloads/IREX/irex /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/themes
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/karl/Downloads/IREX/irex’
root@karl-Inspiron-3520:/home/karl#

Comment: I get cp: omitting directory

Comment: USE THE `-r` OPTION! :-) - *I did mention it - just as a 'folder' instead of a 'directory'...*

Comment: BINGO. It worked. Awesome. I appreciate the help. I have migrated myself away from MS products and I am hoping to reduce my learning curve with Linux and the help from people like yourselves

Comment: Glad to be of help - remember to upvote and mark as answered how you like :-)

Comment: I was able to move the file but now the file cannot be accessed. I do not have permission to view contents.

Comment: `cp` copies the file - if you want to move it use `mv` *(don't use `-r` though)*. The file cannot be accessed by normal users, but you could run `chmod` on it - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can you send me a link to show how to use chmod?

Comment: The manual page I linked to at the bottom of my answer is VERY useful - it has a little table to show which number you need to use *(e.g. `777`)*. There is a short tutorial [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/chmod-command-examples/), of which my answer is the most like Number 6.

Comment: I would not recommend chmodding to 777. That means *any* user of can delete, add, or edit files in there. This is potentially a big security risk. `sudo` or `gksudo` are a MUCH better way to go here.

Comment: Or chnaging the owner @MalteSkoruppa - did you read my edit :-)? Just added a bit more to it.

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you. I have to resolve another issue, which is a Wordpress issue. While I can access the file now, I established the properties being the same as the other themes in my wp-content/themes folder, I cannot access the new folder in my Wordpress Dashboard. So I am going over to WP to try to fix the problem. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: I'm no expert @user225713 - I just now *some* stuff... There is a WordPress site [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) - but it sounds like you have found it anyway ;-).